# Angular and Json Web Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an .net core 2.2 API project that is consumed by an angular application. To secure the API I am using a JWT. Both the API and the SPA are in house applications.

I am using IdentityServer4 with a Resource owner password grant type. I have heard this is not recommended but there are different roles assigned to each user which must be placed in the roles claim of the JWT. This allows .net cores authorization data annotation to grant and restrict access to each route.

The flow I have right now is the user logs into the SPA which sends the credentials to the API. The API uses Identity to validate the credentials. On the successful validation the API sends a request to IdentityServer4 to get a JWT which it then sends back to the SPA. The JWT is then save to local storage to be used on every request.

I am wondering should I be requesting a token directly from IdentityServer4 (IS4 would have access to the Identity context and validate the un/pw) from the SPA? Also is there any other major flaws in the flow that I am overlooking.

Comment: This article may be helpful: https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use [Implicit Flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#implicit) with Angular . Resource owner password grant need your application reads the username and password, which have security issues that may expose the passwords to attackers .

For implementation using Implicit, you can refer to [this article](https://damienbod.com/2015/11/08/oauth2-implicit-flow-with-angular-and-asp-net-5-identity-server/) .

In additon , you could also use Authorization Code with PKCE Flow :

> > For JavaScript-based applications, Implicit is not recommended anymore. Use Authorization Code with PKCE instead.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I’ve started with JWT token but due to some complications later I’ve decided go with custom token. For more detailed explanation please read [custom token](https://medium.com/@hnm.mallesh/custom-token-authentication-asp-net-2-2-core-and-angular-5ef62dc60891)

Following diagram demonstrates request process flow which i've implemented:
[image]